# can't immediately read downloaded text file

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download, readfile

I have an app that download a text file from the web to the app private folder `/data/data/com.example.app`. The file has some data I need to read when it is downloaded.

Code in my app :

```
private class DownloadTextFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        // download text file 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // read text file

        }
```

When I try to read text file, I got an `file not found` error.
When I close the app and reopen it, the app reads the downloaded text file just fine.

EDIT :

haha , iam soooo stupid . thank you all
`how can i make this question as answered`

Comment: Simply check the "Check mark" icon below the posts vote up/vote down arrows on the answer that solves your problem best or you find most suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the Data in `onPostExecute(...)` Method of your Async Class.
Because `onPostExecute(...)` method will be executed after the `doInBackground(...)` method finish it's processing, Where as `onPreExecution(...)` method is called before the `doInbackground(...)` method is called. So currently you are trying to open the file, that is yet to be downloaded in your `doInBackground(...)` method
Your code should be like this:

```
private class DownloadTextFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    // download text file 
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(.....) {
    super.onPostExecute();

    // read text file

    }
```

Comment: That's wrong. `onPostExecute`is not parameterless. Also, reading of the text file should not happen on the main thread but in the background task, as reading a bigger file can take considerable amount of time blocking the mainthread in the meantime.

Comment: That was understood my friend.

Comment: @Tseng : You did really read the documentation ? Well your answer is missing a considerable detail about the Async class. Along with that, the question was about incorrect execution of Anync class and it was not about how to read the text file correctly. You are emphasizing on the read on UI thread point, which is not valid from the question's point of view. Yes, including that in additional information is right.